# Sum of the items in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to do an exercise.. The objective is to sum the items and see which one has the highest value and return, each letter is corresponded in a value. For example, "Babel" worths 10 points (3+1+3+1+2) and "Xadrez" worths 21 points (8+1+2+1+1+8), so the program is supposed to return "Xadrez".
My code's this:

```
    def better(l1):
      dic = {'D':2, 'C':2, 'L':2, 'P':2, 'B':3, 'N':3, 'F':4, 'G':4,
       'H':4, 'V':4, 'J':5, 'Q':6, 'X':8, 'Y':8, 'Z':8}

      for word in dic.keys():
        l1 = []
        best = 0
        sum = 0
        word = word.split()
        word = word.item()

        sum = word.item()

        best = word
        l1 = l1.append(word)
     return best
```

My idea is trying to split each word and sum the value of each letter in each word. Thanks.
Another example: (['ABACO', 'UTOPIA', 'ABADE']) >>'ABACO'

Comment: you seem a bit lost in your code. you're swapping midway the role of `l1` and `dic`. take your time and think it over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by assigning a score value for every letter. This makes it easier to score the words because each letter has a specified value

```
points = \
  { 0: '_' # wild letter
  , 1: 'eaionrtlsu'
  , 2: 'dg'
  , 3: 'bcmp'
  , 4: 'fhvwy'
  , 5: 'k'
  , 8: 'jx'
  , 10: 'qz'
  }
```

You can easily build a `dic` like you have. It's better to define this outside of your scoring function because the `dic` can be reused instead of being recreated each time the function is run (as it does in your code)

```
dic = \
{ letter:score for (score,set) in points.items() for letter in set }
# { '_': 0
# , 'e': 1
# , 'a': 1
# , 'i': 1
# , ...
# , 'x': 8
# , 'q': 10
# , 'z': 10
# }
```

Scoring a word using `dic` is easy thanks to built-in `sum` function

```
def score_word (word):
  return sum (dic[letter] for letter in word)

print (score_word ("babel")) # 9
print (score_word ("xadrez")) # 23
```

Now we need a `max_word` function that can determine the "max" of two words, `w1` and `w2`

```
def max_word (w1, w2):
  if (score_word (w1) > score_word (w2)):
    return w1
  else:
    return w2

print (max_word ("babel", "xadrez")) # xadrez
```

Now it's easy to make a function that can accept any number of words, `max_words`

```
def max_words (w = None, *words):
  if not words:
    return w
  else:
    return max_word (w, max_words (*words))

print (max_words ('abaco', 'utopia', 'abade')) # abaco
print (max_words ()) # None
```

Comment: It wouldn't remind me, but it helped a lot, really! I was trying to do with just one function.. Would your code work?
I was trying again and I did basically the same as you until def max_words, but all in the same function 
Would you mind explaining what '(w = None, *words)' means?
Thanks a lot! @user633183

Comment: It's ineffective to mash everything into a single function. It's worse in every possible way. In Python, each file is already a module, giving you a clean scope to organize your program in.

Comment: wrt `(w = None, *words)`, `w = None` is the first argument `w` and will be assigned a default value of `None` in the event no argument is given. `*words` is a rest parameter that collects the *rest* of the arguments in a single array, `words`. For example, `max_words ("a", "b", "c")`, `w = "a"` and `words = ["b", "c"]`

Comment: However in this expression `max_words (*words)`, `*words` is a spread argument that converts an iterable value into multiple arguments. For example, when `words = ["b", "c"]`, `max_words (*words)` is equivalent to `max_words ("b", "c")`